# search in workspace in xcode 9.4 not working.

Tags: xcode, search, full-text-search, swift4, xcode9.4

[image]

I have tried bunch of different option to search the text in workspace ( text-containing, reference-containing, text-matching, text-starting,  but its not returning any value. In this case I am searching for the content which I already know exist in project but I am still gettin null value.